# Seg fault on fread

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fread

I'm trying to read the header of a .au file (the first 24 bytes, separated into 6 uint32_t's) and print out the encoding, sample rate, and number of channels. Eventually I'll playback the rest of the .au file but right now I'm stuck on getting a segfault when I get to the fread line (I checked via gdb). Why would this be? My code is below. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define AUDIO_FILE_MAGIC (uint32_t)0x02E736E64

#define AUDIO_FILE_ENCODING_MULAW 1
#define AUDIO_FILE_ENCODING_LINEAR_8 2
#define AUDIO_FILE_ENCODING_LINEAR_16 3

#define STEREO 2
#define MONO 1

typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t hdr_size;
    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t encoding;
    uint32_t sample_rate;
    uint32_t channels;
} au_header;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    // Check arguments
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename.au>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    au_header header;
    char str[32];
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    fread(str, 4, 6, f);
    fclose(f);
    uint32_t *intptr = (uint32_t *) str;

    // Remember to change from network order
    header.magic = ntohl(intptr[0]);
    header.hdr_size = ntohl(intptr[1]);
    header.data_size = ntohl(intptr[2]);
    header.encoding = ntohl(intptr[3]);
    header.sample_rate = ntohl(intptr[4]);
    header.channels = ntohl(intptr[5]);

    printf("endcoding: %d\nsample rate: %d\nchannels: %d\n", header.encoding, header.sample_rate, header.channels);
    /* TO DO:

       Implement audio file playback here

    */

}
```

Comment: You don't check if the fopen() succeeds. If f is NULK, you could get a segv.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. It turns out I was just making a silly mistake by not passing the correct filepath as an argument.